# I can't make Codeigniter session work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have written the following code.

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    public function login(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $users=array(
            'name'=>'john',
            'nickname'=>'walker',
            'human'=>true,
          );
        var_dump($this->session->set_userdata($users));

     }
}
```

The `var_dump` is giving me `NULL`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: according to https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L766 `set_userdata` returns nothing ... after you set your userdata you can get access via `$this->session->userdata('name');`

Comment: ... or `$this->session->name` --> "john"

Answer (score 3):

You are var_dump'ing the result of a `set_userdata()` and not the session data. Try this

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    public function login(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $users=array(
            'name'=>'john',
            'nickname'=>'walker',
            'human'=>true,
          );
        $this->session->set_userdata($users);
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

     }
}
```